# SBT publish: Repository for publishing is not specified

Tags: scala, sbt, nexus

I am trying to publish artifact with SBT to remote Nexus repository with command `sbt publish`.

My `build.sbt`:

```
credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus", "nexus.local", "username", "password")
publishTo := Some("Sonatype Nexus" at "http://nexus.local:8080/repository/releases")
```

But I get an error:

```
Repository for publishing is not specified
```

I successfully push to this repository with Maven. Could you help please?

Comment: Do you have multi-project build? Can you try with `publishTo in ThisBuild := `?

Comment: no, it is not multi-project, and I tried with "publishTo in ThisBuild" - didn't help

Comment: can you please add all logs of warm and error levels

Comment: .......
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:publishConfiguration for the full output.
[error] (*:publishConfiguration) Repository for publishing is not specified.
[error] Total time: 86 s, completed Jan 29, 2019 2:54:09 PM

Comment: Have you seen similar question with same log output here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296493/why-does-publishing-plugin-project-fail-with-runtimeexception-repository-for-pu

Comment: yes I saw but looks like it is not relevant to my problem